# Elegant macro if block

Tags: c, macros

I'm currently working on a system where features are enabled by a database check.

```
if(feature_db(id)) {
    //new logic
else {
    //old logic
}
```

I want to replace this with a MACRO.

```
FEATURE_ENABLE(feature_db, id)
    //new logic
FEATURE_DISABLE
    //old logic
END_FEATURE
```

I want to do this because it becomes more clear where these occur and its more explicit what is happening. I want to know if there is just a general more elegant way to to do this?

Comment: _I want to do this because it becomes more clear_ - It looks less clear IMHO

Comment: ^^ Exactly that, seconding @Ed

Comment: Is it more clear to you because you used `ALL_CAPS`, thus shouting at you what is being done?

Comment: people (not me) are downvoting your question because you are describing a technique that has been used as long a the `C` language has existed. This technique has been shown to be a "Really Bad Idea" over and over.  Don't do it!  [Note another way to describe what you are trying to do is: You are implementing your own private language using C macros.  This private language may be clear to you, but it will not be clear to any other developer who works on the code.

Comment: Keep a few things in mind: You're losing the ability to decide whether these features should be enabled at runtime. Also, if your macros are causing compiling issues, then you're not using them right. Macros themselves don't cause "compiling issues" - you should be able to fix them, then decide whether you want to keep them

Comment: For what it's worth, I think it's dumb that this question was closed for the debugging help reason. *Too Broad* may apply here, but I think you got the downvotes and close reason more because people disagree with your plan than the actual formulation of your question. You should take out the comment about macros causing compiling errors so it's focused on your question about readability.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree that this question should be closed for lacking a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, the OP did not post the macro definitions that he tried.

Comment: Thanks for the time and feedback. It seems I'll have to continue to explore the solution myself.

Answer (score 8):

No, your resulting code is less clear for any competent C programmer: C programmers know about `if` and function calls. They do not know about the syntax and semantics of your custom macros that do not follow general convention. As a consequence, they first need to discover what the macros do, and ensure that using them in this way is in fact correct and safe — neither of which is obvious from your code.

However, you can make your initial code clearer by naming the function better and adjusting its parameters, e.g.:

```
if (feature_enabled(feature_db, id)) {
    …
} else {
    …
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would normally agree with you here but the situation and scale I'm facing calls for something different. Its at the scale of 200K different examples that occur. I would prefer the macro because it allows me to automate the removal of this later.